# Deleting multiple keys in redis-rb

Tags: ruby, redis

Using redis-rb in a Rails app, the following doesn't work:

```
irb> keys = $redis.keys("autocomplete*")
=> ["autocomplete_foo", "autocomplete_bar", "autocomplete_bat"]
irb> $redis.del(keys)
=> 0
```

This works fine:

```
irb> $redis.del("autocomplete_foo", "autocomplete_bar")
=> 2
```

Am I missing something obvious? The source is just:

```
# Delete a key.
def del(*keys)
  synchronize do
    @client.call [:del, *keys]
  end
end
```

which looks to me like it should work to pass it an array...?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A little coding exploration of the way the splat operator works:

```
def foo(*keys)
  puts keys.inspect
end

>> foo("hi", "there")
["hi", "there"]

>> foo(["hi", "there"])
[["hi", "there"]]

>> foo(*["hi", "there"])
["hi", "there"]
```

So passing in a regular array will cause that array to be evaluated as a single item, so that you get an array inside an array within your method. If you preface the array with * when you call the method:

```
$redis.del(*keys)
```

That lets the method know to unpack it/not to accept any further arguments. So that should solve the problem that you're having!

Just for the sake of further clarification, this works:

```
>> foo("hello", *["hi", "there"])
```

This causes a syntax error:

```
>> foo("hello", *["hi", "there"], "world")
```

Comment: deleting multiple (thousands) keys causes:

SystemStackError: stack level too deep, reported in this issue https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/issues/122. This is solved by directly calling the method on the client: `$redis.client.call [:del, *keys]`

Answer (score 18):

For a Rails app I'm working on, I needed to test the results of loading and unloading redis data.

The namespace is determined by the environment, avoids interacting with development. This worked well.

```
def clear_redis_cache
  keys = $redis.keys "#{namespace}*"
  $redis.del(*keys) unless keys.empty?
end
```

Comment: Monkey-patching redis namespace for this https://gist.github.com/mahemoff/c3abf31d5eeda2b2ac751dccd5182cb9

Comment: -1 because the KEYS command is not a production ready command. This will cause a blocking connection and will affects the other commands. See more https://redis.io/topics/latency

Answer (score 6):

This is better achieved using the enumerator returned by `scan_each`.

```rb
scan_each(match: 'autocomplete_*').each do |key|
  del key
end
```

This does not load all of the matching keys into memory at once, so it will not be limited by local memory.

Comment: _THIS_, so much of this! I was using the original poster's method of scanning the entire database for matching keys, then trying to delete an array containing thousands of keys. It was taking over an hour. This `scan_each` method cut it down to 10 minutes!